# Why three.js object is not rendering to my canvas?

Tags: javascript, html, css, three.js, webgl

**Hello guys I'm trying to render this webgl object to my own canvas because i want to style it but it don't what I"m doing wrong because it's not working. I can not figure out how to render a Three-js scene in a canvas. I tried**

```html
var renderer = new THREE.WebGL1Renderer({
    canvas: canvas1Ref
});
```

**but i don't know why it's not working**

**javascript code**

```
//scene
var scene = new THREE.Scene();
var camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(
    75,
    window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight,
    .01,
    1000
);

var canvas1Ref = document.getElementById("canvas1");
//renderer
var renderer = new THREE.WebGL1Renderer({
    canvas: canvas1Ref
});
renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);

//controls
/*
var controls = new THREE.OrbitControls(camera,renderer.domElement);
controls.update();*/

var loader = new GLTFLoader();

//car
var object;
loader.load("3d-object/tented-car/scene.gltf" , function(gltf){
    object = gltf.scene;
    scene.add(gltf.scene);
});

//bg
scene.background = new THREE.Color(0x000000);

//light 
var light = new THREE.DirectionalLight(0xffffff, 1.7, 10);
scene.add(light);

light.shadow.mapSize.width = 512; // default
light.shadow.mapSize.height = 512; // default
light.shadow.camera.near = 5; // default
light.shadow.camera.far = 500; // default


camera.position.set(0,1,5);



function animate(){
    requestAnimationFrame(animate);
    object.rotation.y += 0.004
    renderer.render(scene, camera);
}

animate();
```

**html code**

````
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>3d model</title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
    
    <h1>hello world</h1>

    <canvas id="object1">

    </canvas>




    <script src="modules/three.js"></script>
    <script src="modules/OrbitControls.js"></script>
    <script type="module" src="modules/GLTFLoader.js"></script>
    <script type="module" src="object.js"></script>
</body>
</html>```

**Also I get this error**
[Error][1]
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/fULSe.png


**Thanks in advance**
````

Comment: seems that you use `getElementById` incorrectly, because your canvas' id is `object1` in html file, but you use `document.getElementById("canvas1")`, than you can't get the canvas

Comment: thank you, hard question simple solution i figured it out after 1 hour.